# Need help resolving data contention in parallel construction of Eigen arrays

Tags: c++, multithreading, profiling, eigen

I have just run a concurrency profiler on my program and have found a line of code that is frequently contended between threads in memory, namely;

```
// declarations shown here to clarify type:
size_t const timeSteps;
typedef Eigen::Array<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> Signal2D;
Signal2D Activations(timeSteps, desc.length()); // this line is contended
```

Note that I have declared `#define EIGEN_DONT_PARALLELIZE` to avoid implicit parallelization of Eigen operations.

The above line is executed concurrently over several threads, but the `desc` instance is a class that is local to the thread. So why is this piece of code being contended between threads?

In the VS2013 profiler, it says that the specific code being contended is `Eigen::DenseStorage<float,-1,-1,-1,0>::resize`. Why is this occuring? Is Eigen somehow keeping track of which arrays are created and destroyed between threads? Why? And how do I switch it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is because this resize function perform memory allocation through system calls to malloc. So I think that the actual issue is in malloc. The best solution would be to avoid dynamic memory allocation by preallocating the needed arrays and move to a more C-like API for Activations().

Comment: Well the array sizes aren't known at compile-time, so do you mean allocating the memory in serial before entering the parallel loop? That would be a royal pain since the loop is far outside that scope, but it's doable I suppose!

Comment: yes, each thread should allocate what it needs first, and then loop through its associated data.